# JavaBean not working in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

My aim is to import my class file in my index.jsp and reading over the internet I learned I'm supposed to use JavaBeans.

So here is my class file placed in WEB-INF/classes/jBean/Bucket.class -

```
package jBean;
import java.sql.* ;
import java.math.* ;

public class Bucket implements java.io.Serializable{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Bucket obj = new Bucket();
    obj.DBConn();
}

public static void DBConn(){
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentfeedback","root","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");
        while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("Roll_No")+"  "+rs.getString("Name")+"  "+rs.getString("Pass"));
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

And here is my index.jsp where I want to import the class file -

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="jBean" class="jBean.Bucket" scope="session" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Doing this I get this error message on executing index.jsp file

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

So, my query is how shall I import the class file, Bucket.java?
And is there any other way to import the file to index.jsp other than using javBeans?
Please help me with this as I can't find what I'm looking for. Maybe cause I might not be asking the right thing.

*All I want to do is import the class file Bucket.java to the index.jsp*

May God help the helping soul.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception

Comment: What you have shown us looks ok. Did you restart Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, I've done the basic. No luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963052/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp

Comment: I added the classes directory to the classpath and all I'm getting is 'Empty Library'.

Answer (score 2):

Did you observed your project folder structure.
The classes referenced by the jsp must be in the classpath.
And the classpath includes WEB-INF/classes. 
The location of the jsp is of no importance.

[question regarding jsp page import and <jsp:useBean id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886392/question-regarding-jsp-page-import-and-jspusebean-id)